# When to create a separate table in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I am confused while designing rethinkdb tables/documents. When do I create a separate table and when do I store it in the same document. Should joins be avoided as much as possible or should we use them extensively. What are the advantages of storing data in a separate table vs storing it in the parent document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

The database should be architected around what your data will look like. `.join` should not necessarily be avoided. In many cases, `.join` will improve the performance of your database.

Here's some things to consider:

1. You want to reduce complexity. If it makes sense to store everything in a document, then you should do that. If it makes sense to use `.join`, you should do that.
2. Updating a document is expensive. It's better if you can avoid it. That might mean just writing everything in one document or breaking things apart if you'll have to update that document frequently.
3. Parsing complex documents (with many nested properties) is expensive. Try to reduce the complexity of your documents if you're reading them frequently.
4. `.join` is not supported in `.changes` (yet!). What decision you take depends if and how you'll be using changefeeds.

Here are a couple of scenarios and how to go about them:

1. If table A has a one-to-many to B and you won't be creating/updating either one frequently, it's better to just write everything into one document.
2. If table A has a one-to-many to B and you won't be creating/updating a lot of As, but you will be creating/updating a lot of Bs it's better to store them in two different tables and use `.join`.
3. If table A has a one-to-many to B and B has a very complex nested JSON structure, it's better to store them in different tables and use `.join`, since reading A would be very expensive otherwise (unless you'll be reading the Bs in As every single time).
4. If table A has a one-to-many to B and you'll be extensively using changefeeds with only the data on A, it's better to keep B in a separate table.
5. If table A has a one-to-many to B and you'll be extensively using changefeeds with the data on both A and B, you'll want to keep all the data in the same document.